# Push entitlement not appearing in distribution Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, xcode5, provisioning-profile

When submitting my iOS application with push notifications to the App Store I received the infamous "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" email:

> Your app appears to include API used to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the "aps-environment" entitlement. If your app uses the Apple Push Notification service, make sure your App ID is enabled for Push Notification in the Provisioning Portal, and resubmit after signing your app with a Distribution provisioning profile that includes the "aps-environment" entitlement.

I have already tried revoking and re-creating all production profiles, provisioning profiles and APNS production certificates. Push Notifications are enabled on my App ID, and the correct APNS certificates are configured.

The problem seems to be that even tho everything is configured correctly in the iOS dev center, my downloaded provisioning profiles do not have the required push notification entitlement (aps-environment). The attached image shows that only In App Purches and Game Center are enabled for my distribution provisioning profile (Xcode 5).

[image: Notice the missing push notification Entitlement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After retrying and reinstalling all profiles and certificates and cleaning my whole keychain it suddenly worked. I have successfully submitted the app with the "aps-environment" entitlement. As it seems the Provisioning Profiles in the Xcode 5 settings **never** display Push Notifications under the Entitlements tab.

Comment: Did you receive email from apple "Missing Push Notification Entitlement" even this time? Although later your submission was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same email from Apple using XCode 7.3.1. What I did to solve the problem was, in my Project in Xcode:

1. Under Capabilities > Set PUSH notification ON
2. Under Build-Settings > Code Signing > Code Signing Identity set the developer cert for debug and the distribution cert for release, as is shown here:

[image]

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to developer portal, edit the provisional profile for **distribution** and download it again after recreating it.

Pay attention to **delete** the old provisional profile from your mac. Also check you are signing with it on build settings.

This should work.

Comment: Edited existing distribution provisioning profile, then deleted the old one in my Keychain and made sure it did not appear in my Xcode profile and ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles. Then downloaded and installed the new profile and it still isn't showing Push Notifications. The profile also appears under the Code Signing tab in Xcode. I'm lost.

Comment: @Jesse Are you sure you edited and added the push on the developer portal?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, im using ionic to generate the project, i solved the problem setting the path in Target -> Build Setting -> Code signing entitlements -> Release, manually

[image]